# How do I clear the cache in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: caching, pentaho, pdi

I am trying to run Pentaho Data Integration (ver. 8.3) in my Windows machine and it is not working.
These are the steps I tried to make it work:

- Tried rebooting the machine without success.
- Also tried to run the **Spoon.bat** command directly from the directory where Pentaho is located, but it did not work.
- Checked if my java installation changed since the last time it worked, it did not, what can be happening?

In a support chat I read someone was able to fix the problem by clearing the cache, but did not explain how to do it, how do I clean the cache?

Comment: why not start with the basics. Do you have a java version installed that is compatible with Pentaho? What happens if you start spoon.bat from the command line? Any error messages? Environment variable JAVA_HOME is set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps to clear the cache in a Windows environment:

1. Go to C:\Users\youruser.kettle
2. Look for the file db.cache-* (I have PDI version 8.3, my file is named db.cache-8.3.0.0-371)
   [image]
3. Edit the file with any editor (i.e. Notepad) and erase all content

It worked for me!

Comment: This solved my problem, here sir, have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed >jdk java 1.8 environment?
And you should open powershell or other terminal to check: java -version
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you should run **.\data-integration\set-pentaho-env.bat**; It will set pdi environment. The most important is the Java HOME, and JAVA Version. PDI 8.3 can only run in JAVA 1.8 and above.